# Javascript, can't figure out why the code isn't working

Tags: javascript, percentage

`body`

```
<form>I want to know the
<select id="birthdeath">
    <option value="birth">birth rate</option>
    <option value="death">death rate</option>
</select>
<p></p>of  
<select id="country">
    <option value="neth">Netherlands</option>
<option value="ger">Germany</option>
    <option value="france">France</option>
    <option value="bras">Brasil</option>
</select>
in: <input type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" id="years" placeholder="21"/> years

    <p></p>
    <input id="calculate" type="button" value="calculate!" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="div2">The birth or death rate of your country will be ... </div>
</div>
</div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
var number = {
    birth: {
        neth: 11,
        france: 13,
    ger:8,
        bras: 17,
    },
    death: {
        neth: 8,
        france: 9,
        ger: 11,
    bras: 6,
    }
};



document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var birthdeath = document.getElementById('birthdeath').value;
    var nationality = document.getElementById('country').value;

    var new = new [birthdeath][nationality] 
    var total=Math.round(new*1.10)

    document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "The birth/ death rate of your country will be <b>" + total + "</b>.";
}, false);</script>

  </body>
```

Comment: what is `new [birthdeath][nationality]`? and how would you multiply that, *whatever* it is, by a number?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit wrong with it... You can't name a var new for one it is a reserved word.

Second you have random text living after your form opening tag. But before any element.

Third in your "new" var creation I'm not sure what you are trying to create with [] [] there isn't a meaning for that.

Fourth not sure if your code got cut but there are also two non matched closing divs near the bottom for script

Comment: Thanks I changed it, but it still isn't working. Sorry I'm new at this.